# Can I publish a post with "say what you are doing", using Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Using Facebook iOS SDK, is it possible to publish a post to my timeline and set the "say what you are doing" field ?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there's no API for that.